# Using Inner Join the same result is returned multiple times

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

I have used the following query:

`OrderMaster` table:

```
OrderId
UserId - F.K
```

`Users` table:

```
Id - P.K
Name
Email
Mobilenumber
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(o.Id as varchar(50)) as ID, 
    CAST(o.Name as varchar(50)) as Name,
    CAST(o.ContactNumber as varchar(50)) as Mobilenumber, 
    o.Email 
FROM 
    ordermaster as t1 
INNER JOIN
    Users as o ON t1.UserId<> o.Id
```

The results look like this:

```
Id  Name   Mobilenumber  Email
-------------------------------------------
1   xxxx   252548878     dfj@dkjf.com
2   yyyy   422557879     dsfsdf@kdjf.com
1   xxxx   252548878     dfj@dkjf.com
2   yyyy   422557879     dsfsdf@kdjf.com
```

Why is the same result returned multiple times? Please clarify me.

Comment: This join makes no sense `Users as o ON t1.UserId<> o.Id`

Comment: Please also tell us what the **datatypes** are for those columns !

Comment: why i want to take data's from users table what is not in Ordermaster table. is it not correct?

Comment: Those columns are integer. i want the users who are not in order master i should take this.

Comment: @Duk, see my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your join condition is <> and not =, each record in User join with all the records in Ordermaster that have a different id, giving the same result multiple times.
If you want to get all the Users which are not in Ordermaster then you can do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ordermaster WHERE u.Id = Id)
```